# Remove [repeat] and [repetition]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I don't think we need [repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeat) and [repetition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repetition). They have 2 subscribers between them, but over 800 Questions. No one will miss them.

Comment: I could do [tag:repetition], but [tag:repeat] is too many Questions.